# Error: Could not find matching close tag for "<%="

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

i just wanna ask simple i have an error like this

> Error: Could not find matching close tag for "<%=".
>       at C:\Users\User\Documents\latihannode.js\nodejs8\library\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:693:19
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at Template.generateSource (C:\Users\User\Documents\latihannode.js\nodejs8\library\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:678:15)
>       at Template.compile (C:\Users\User\Documents\latihannode.js\nodejs8\library\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:557:12)
>       at Object.compile (C:\Users\User\Documents\latihannode.js\nodejs8\library\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:389:16)
>       at handleCache (C:\Users\User\Documents\latihannode.js\nodejs8\library\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:212:18)
>       at tryHandleCache (C:\Users\User\Documents\latihannode.js\nodejs8\library\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:251:16)
>       at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (C:\Users\User\Documents\latihannode.js\nodejs8\library\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:482:10)
>       at View.render (C:\Users\User\Documents\latihannode.js\nodejs8\library\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:135:8)
>       at tryRender (C:\Users\User\Documents\latihannode.js\nodejs8\library\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:640:10)

and this is that i used code using ejs

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <% for(let i=0; i<nav.length; i++) { %>
        <li>
          <a href="<%=nav[i].link"><%nav[i].title%></a>
        </li>
        <%}%>

      </ul>
```

This is from my NodeJS js file. when i render the "index" i passed the index variable to EJS

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render(
    'index',
    {
      nav: [{ link: '/buku', title: 'Buku' },
        { link: '/penulis', title: 'Penulis' }],
      title: 'library'
    }
  );
});
```

Comment: Notice the `href`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should close `href` with `%>`.

```
 <a href="<%=nav[i].link%>"><%nav[i].title%></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but the error was inside the ejs file I was importing not in the file where I was calling the import. It is easy to lose track of the opens and closes.